# Hibernate many to many delete data from table1 table1_table2 and table2

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, cascading-deletes

I have two entities Student and Lesson

There are many to many relationship. The definition of Student and Lesson like the bellow :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Integer age;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(name = "student_lesson", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lesson_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Lesson> lesson= new HashSet<>();
....
```

And Lesson

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lesson")
public class Lesson {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private int credit;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.REMOVE
    },
    mappedBy = "lesson")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
```

When I run remove command in StudentDao , the data in student, student_lesson are deleted but lesson doesn't.

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void deleteStudent(Student student) {

        try {
            entityManager.remove(student);
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Student doesn't exist");
        } finally {
            //entityManager.close();
        }
    }
```

But when I run entityManager.remove(lesson) in LessonDao all the related data in lesson, student_lesson and student are deleted.
But I don't want the data in student table to be deleted. What should I do to prevent the data in student table not to delete?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are providing  `CascadeType.REMOVE` in your Lesson Entity. Just remove this cascading and it should work.

Comment: When I remove it then it throws an exception. When I add CascadeType.REMOVE It removes data from lesson, student_lesson and student. I don't want to delete entry from student.